# Using StructureMap, how do you explicitly trigger the reinstantiation of a object with InstanceScope.Singleton?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap, integration-testing

I have an integration test harness where I want to teardown and then re-instantiate some of the singleton-scoped objects I've registered with StructureMap, after and before each test.

This way I can simulate the actual run time environment, but not have the singleton's state being passed from one test to another.  Maybe this isn't a great way to do an integration test, but I'm running out of alternative solutions (read open to any advice).

So can an object with `InstanceScope.Singleton`, be re-instantiated?

What's the best way to do re-instantiate a singleton-scoped object with StructureMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not much of a StructureMap user, but in IoC containers in general, you shouldn't try to do this. Think of a singleton **x** that depends on another singleton **y**. Now re-instantiate **y**. But **x** would still hold a reference to the old instance of **y**!

The lifetime of a singleton is supposed to be the same as its container, so if you want to kill an instance of a singleton, you'll have to kill its container. You can scope this by using a [nested container](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2010/02/10/nested-containers-in-structuremap-2-6-1.aspx).

Comment: Well, in this situation I think it was acceptable because there were only two to three objects scoped singleton, and non of them touched each other.  I solved this problem using nested containers as you suggest here.

Answer (score 1):

ObjectFactory.Initialize will re-initialise the container configuration. Do that in your test setup.